# Why are Java truststores identical across all installed JDK versions?

Tags: java, tomcat

I was troubleshooting an SSLHandshakeException on my Apache Tomcat server when I noticed some very weird behaviors of the JDK truststore (`<jdk-root>/lib/security/cacerts`) on the server.

Across all the many JDKs installed on the server (multiple major and minor versions) wherever I look at a truststore under a specific installation it is completely identical to all the others.

Additionally if I import a new certificate using this command `keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias <somealias> -file <somecertificate>.cer -keystore <jdk-root>/lib/security/cacerts -storepass <password>` this newly imported certificate is immediately also included in all other truststores under different JDK installations. No restart of the JVM is necessary for the running tomcat applications to use this newly imported certificate either.

Both the automatic reload and shared truststore is in stark contrast to what I experience in my local dev environment, which is why I'm puzzled by this.

Can someone point me in the direction of what is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because "cacerts" is a symbolic link on your server. Check it with `ls -la <jdk-root>/lib/security/`

Comment: Hi Tristan, thanks for the answer. I can see it is indeed a symlink for `/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/java/cacerts`. I am very much wondering how this came to be, though. I am not the only developer who has access to this server but I can all but guarantee nobody set this up manually. Can you explain how/why this is a symlink?

Comment: How did you install the JDK? Versions packaged by your distribution almost certainly centralize the management of certificates.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Using yum on Centos 7. So that is simply expected behavior then?

Comment: Yes, you usually assume than an RPM package will integrate more smoothly into your distribution, than the upstream installer.